# How can I operate on a Mercurial bundle with JavaHg?

Tags: java, mercurial, bundle, javahg

I have a `x.hg` bundle file that I would like to inspect with JavaHg. I could of course unbundle it onto my repository, but I would like to open it and see the changesets inside instead. Is this possible?

Comment: (This question was asked to me in private — I'm re-posting it here with an answer in case others have the same question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`Bundle` class](http://javahg.aragost.com/apidocs/com/aragost/javahg/Bundle.html) to open the bundle. It constructs a *bundle repository* where the bundle has been [overlaid on top of a base repository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LookingIntoBundles).

In normal Mercurial you do this with the `--repository` flag:

```sh
$ cd your-base-repository
$ hg log --repository x.hg
```

In JavaHg you first open the base repository and then construct a `Bundle` using that:

```java
Repository repo = Repository.open(new File("your-base-repository"));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(repo, new File("x.hg"));
```

You can then get the changesets from the bundle:

```java
List<Changeset> changesets = bundle.getChangesets();
```